Why does the record get queued in the Transactional API Journey if the response shows 202 accepted successful via POSTMAN?
The following is my Payload
POST : https://{{et_subdomain}}.rest.marketingcloudapis.com/messaging/v1/email/messages/{{$guid}}
{
    "definitionKey": "MF_Software_Purchase",
    "recipient": {
        "contactKey": "xxxyx@gmail.com",
        "to": "xxxzy@gmail.com",
        "attributes": {            
            "ContentVersion": "STATIC_LINK",
            "OrderNum": "MFW140980hj",
            "LicenseKey": "PTHDSB294-VH6467135-3181Y72",
            "ProductDetails": "Guitar",
            "BrandId": "MF",
            "DownloadLink": "http://account.avid.com",
            "BillingFname": "abdj"
        }
    }
}

below is the response :
{
    "requestId": "4cbb164c-faf3-445d-9004-f24c87ddd180",
    "errorcode": 0,
    "responses": [
        {
            "messageKey": "3bed75e1-8403-4ee6-aff5-399e0c65081a"
        }
    ]
}


have you retrieved delivery status of that message key to review any issue?

You Job may not also be created due to ampscript errors

202 is an acknowledgement of you request getting in the door. Whether the concert will happen is a different matter.  This is common with async APIs.

I would suggest doing a send preview with the email to the record in the DE to observe any ampscript errors that are stopping your job from sending
you may be have invalid attributes in your ampscript
